# Failover queue should not deliver the messages until the actual queue start delivering the messages

Tags: tomcat7, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using ActiveMQ implementation for sending messages to the queue. When there is a problem in the queue I am redirecting all my messages to another queue using failover mechanism.

But my requirement is that the failover queue messages should not be consumed by the consumer until the the messages in the first queue are consumed by the consumer.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this scenario? Thanks in advance.

Here is my XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://172.16.121.146:61617" />
</bean>
<bean id="cscoDest" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
  <constructor-arg value="STOCKS.CSCO" />
</bean>
<!--The message listener-->
<bean id="portfolioListener" class="my.test.jms.Listener"></bean>
<!--Spring DMLC-->
<bean id="cscoConsumer"     class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer102">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="destination" ref="cscoDest" />
  <property name="messageListener" ref="portfolioListener" />
  <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
</bean>
<!--Spring JMS Template-->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="stockPublisher" class="my.test.jms.SpringPublisher">
  <property name="template" ref="jmsTemplate" />
  <property name="destinations">
    <list>
      <ref local="cscoDest" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ failover mechanism is there to let the client fail over to another ActiveMQ broker if the connection with the current broker goes down.

Your requirement that the 2nd queue should not deliver messages until the first queue is empty is very odd. What happends if someone terminates the ActiveMQ server by pulling the plug? There might still be unprocessed messages on that server, but you cannot process them.

What you want is a [master slave setup](http://activemq.apache.org/shared-file-system-master-slave.html) that shares a disk area (network share somewhere). Then a second broker can pick up where the master broker stopped working.

Comment: For the above requirement i have tried failover mechanism sometimes i was not able to receive all the messages and for sometimes i was able to receive already received messages also.i thought the broker got stuck some where

Comment: Already received messages? You might have some issue in your code (acks that does not get sent, since you do CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE you need to be 100% sure your code handles it correctly).

Comment: if i use single broker it is working properly the above condition arises only if i use failover mechanism